# Stored Procedure: Unable to execute after creation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure which does four things:

1. create a table
2. Alter the created table with a new column
3. Update the new column based on a condition
4. Alter table again to drop a column.

I created the stored procedure but cannot execute. I get this error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition'

I have checked all the columns and their datatype to ensure they match so I am at my wit's end as to where it has gone wrong. This is my first time writing a stored procedure, so it may be that my code structure is completely wrong. I have attached a simplified code here showing the basic structure and I am hoping if someone can have a look if the structure is right and shed some light!

Thanks a lot

Michelle

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProcedure 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('newTable') IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE newTable 
        (
            [name] [nvarchar] (256) NOT NULL,
            [id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [date] [datetime2] (7) NULL 
        )
    END;

    TRUNCATE TABLE newTable;

    INSERT INTO newTable 
        SELECT [name], [id], [date]
        FROM table1;

    ALTER TABLE newTable 
        ADD [Flag] [nvarchar](2) NULL;

    UPDATE newTable
    SET [Flag] = 1
    WHERE YEAR([date]) = 2020;

    ALTER TABLE newTable
        DROP COLUMN [date];
END;
```

Comment: The stored procedure drops the `date` column at the end of its first execution. Subsequent executions will fail because they cannot insert into `newTable` without a `date` column.

Comment: If you're **creating** the table inside the stored procedure - why not create it with **all** the columns it needs from the beginning? You could also provide the **values** for the `Flag` column in the `INSERT` statement ..... but really: you should **NOT** be creating "permanent" tables inside stored procedures - really bad idea .....

Comment: What marc said. Stored procedures - especially ones that you intend to execute more than one - should not be creating permanent tables. You omit many things that need to be considered. First and foremost is permissions. And a dba should determine on which filegroup to place this table, the indexes needed, constraints (where is your primary key), etc. Designing databases is a completely different skill from writing tsql.

Comment: Your code is also very inefficient. No need to truncate a table after it is newly created. Nor should you be inserting a bunch of rows, adding a null column, and then immediately changing the inserted rows (very inefficient) to set that added column. This could all be done just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Guru's comments above, rather create the table as it should be created originally, then update data in it accordingly with your SP.

I altered your SP to work, however, this is still not the correct way to actually use a SP.

See below altered SP:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProcedure 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID('newTable') IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE newTable 
        (
            [id]    int primary key identity,
            [name]  nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
            [date]  datetime2 (7) NULL ,
            [Flag]  nvarchar(2) NULL
        )
    END;

    INSERT INTO newTable    (
                            [name],
                            [date]
                            )
        SELECT
            [name],
            [date]
        FROM table1;

    UPDATE newTable
    SET [Flag] = 1
    WHERE YEAR([date]) = 2020;

END;
```

I removed the code to drop the Date Column as this is ill advised.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advice!! It has helped me a lot to rethink about the structure. It’s a business requirement that I have to use stored procedure to create a bunch of temp tables using dim and fact tables, do a bunch of calculations on dim values, and then drop all the values and only keep the keys and calculated fields in the final table. 
I have amended the code, have the calculated fields done in the temp tables, and created the final table with only the keys and calculated fields and the execution worked.  
Thanks very much @Birel for your code!!